# How to store json code in database table column in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

Hi guys i am trying to store my json data into my datatbase table column.

Here is my sample json code..this data only i am trying to store in db.

```
    {
  "template": {
    "question_section": {
      "section_data": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "section": "text section",
          "properties": {
            "font_size": "14",
            "font_weight": "400",
            "font_color": "#000000",
            "row": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "solution_section": {
      "section_data": []
    }
  }
}
```

here is my sample code:

```
function updateJson(field_id, from_where, section_counter, property_name, ques_section_counter, sol_section_counter)
{
    if(from_where == 'question')
    {
        let prop_value = $('#'+field_id).val();

        template_json.template.question_section.section_data[ques_section_counter-1].properties[property_name] = prop_value;
    }
    else if(from_where == 'solution')
    {
        let prop_value = $('#'+field_id).val();

        template_json.template.solution_section.section_data[sol_section_counter-1].properties[property_name] = prop_value;
    }
    $('#code_json').html(JSON.stringify(template_json, undefined, 2));
}
```

This is one sample function that this is how i am getting json code and all..that above json wwhole code i would like to store.

Here is my form code:

```
    $template->template_json = $request->input('');//this is the column
```

Can anyone help me on how can i store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to save it as text in database like this:

```
$template->template_json = json_encode($request->input(''));
```

and then when you want to use it convert it to object before like this:

```
$template->template_json = json_decode($template->template_json);
```

Comment: add what you tried in your edit page and edit controller in your question for me to help you

Comment: yes..shall we make a group an connect so that i can shpw you there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679847/how-to-get-json-values-from-db-in-edit-page-in-laravel

Comment: Hi did you check the question and have you understood the problem

Comment: Thats just small piece of code.if you didnt understand that will give you the full code